# I can be doughnut? Well rhyming is hard. - What am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

```
I can walk and jump and make things me,

I can bring happiness, play sports and cut,

I can possess great poise and beauty,

I can be baked, loud and doughnut.
```

**What am I?**

HINT:

> If we all need to wait, should we form a cue?

Comment: are you a torus?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry I'm not a torus.

Comment: Is the word "queue" misspelled intentionally in the hint? or do you really intend "cue" as in "signal someone gives"?

Comment: @Nzall  I don't mean a signal.

Comment: So the spelling of cue is deliberate?

Comment: @Nzall Yes.  It's deliberate.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Dunno how to spoiler but;

> Are you a stick?

I can walk and jump and make things me,

> walking stick,  pogo stick , make things stick

I can bring happiness, play sports and cut,

> a large variety of sticks can be smoked (in dutch a joint is aka a "sticky") to make you "happy", there are polo sticks and hockey sticks, and in fact cutting sticks used in the printing industry.

I can possess great poise and beauty,

> lipstick and walking sticks both fit the bill imo.

I can be baked, loud and doughnut.

> some ***** invented a "donut stick" wich can in fact be baked! And a boomstick is either slang for a gun, tnt or a device to make your headphones go louder.

No idea what the hint is though... stick around while we find out...

**OP's Intended Explanation**

I can walk and jump and make things me,

> Walking stick, pogo stick, glue stick

I can bring happiness, play sports and cut,

> Joy stick, hockey stick, chop stick

I can possess great poise and beauty,

> Majestic (Sorry!)

I can be baked, loud and doughnut.

> Bread stick, drum stick, doughnut stick (because it rhymes but it does exist!)

And the hint was

> A cue stick

Comment: To spoiler just add >! before the line

Comment: Well done.  I'll edit with a full explanation. +1

Comment: Thank you for the spoilers. No idea about the hint.

Comment: What do you mean about rhyming?

Comment: @BrentHackers ... I wouldn't go the route of obscurity for the sake of a rhyme, especially if it doesn't form a good sentence structure.  You know riddles don't *have* to rhyme, right?

Comment: I was about to post "a maple tree" following much of this reasoning plus seeds, maple donuts

Comment: @feelinferrety I know- I know.  Most of mine don't.  I like when they do...

Answer (score 10):

Are you

> high ?

I can walk and jump and make things me,

> highwalk (on a rope?) highjumping and placing things on a high place

I can bring happiness, play sports and cut,

> happiness = being in high spirits, playing sports on a high level, a high cut (i.e. in clothing)

I can possess great poise and beauty,

> highness (as with royalty)

I can be baked, loud and doughnut.

> being high/stoned, with high volume... and doughnuts?

Don't know for sure, English is not my first language.

Comment: I'm not high.  How dare you?!  Good explanations though. +1

Comment: First time I saw this answer, I only had time to look at the first spoiler and I thought the genuine answer was intended to be the other high ~crying with laughter~

Comment: Me too. Specially in the part of happyness. I thought he would be saying being high = fake happiness induced by mrjn.

Answer (score 5):

Are you

> A trick shot in a game of pool?

I can walk and jump and make things me,

> Trick shots like walk the dog, jumping the cue ball

I can bring happiness, play sports and cut,

> Happiness if you win, pool is a sport, cut is another type of shot

I can possess great poise and beauty,

> Trick shots require poise and have a certain beauty

I can be baked, loud and doughnut.

> I'm at a loss here, other pool jargon?

It fits with the hint though.

> If we all need to wait, should we form a cue?
>  Pool has a cue ball.

Comment: I'm not a trick shot.  I wouldn't know pool jargon either :) +1

Comment: This was my guess too, charging! I'm very curious of the answer now...

Answer (score 4):

Are you

> Spring ?

I can walk and jump and make things me

> Spring can walk down stairs, jump and makes things spring.

I can bring happiness, play sports and cut,

> The season spring brings happiness, spring sports.

I can possess great poise and beauty,

> The season spring or "curves" of the spring

I can be baked, loud and doughnut.

> Spring rolls, spring doughnuts (or sprinkles on doughnut)

Comment: I'm not a spring.  Good explanations though.  Not a bad fit all round  (except maybe cut and loud?).  Love the walking explanation. +1

Comment: Too bad, signed up to SE just for your great puzzle. I will give it some more thought. I will be looking forward to see the right answer!

Comment: Thanks.  Just for that, another hint coming your way. :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> Corn/Porcorn?

I can walk and jump and make things me

> Corn jumps when it turns into popcorn

I can bring happiness, play sports and cut,

> Popcorn brings happiness to loads of people, specially on movies. And again it does sports when the corns 'jumps' into popcorn.

I can possess great poise and beauty

> Corn is rather a beautiful vegetable? In literature corn is usually related to wellness and richness.

I can be baked, loud and doughnut.

> Corn can be baked, it's loud when turn into popcorn. And... there are doughnuts with popcorn and made out of corn?

Comment: It's not corn.  A few good fits though.  +1

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> a rope?

I can walk and jump and make things me,

> Tightrope walking, rope jumping, and roping things in

I can bring happiness, play sports and cut,

> Ropes can be used for hanging decorations, swings, Piñatas, etc.., which bring happiness. They can be used in sports (tug of war, jumping, etc...). They can also be used to cut through soft objects like candles and PVC pipes.

I can possess great poise and beauty,

> When used for hanging paintings, or holiday decorations.

I can be baked, loud and doughnut.

> Baked with roped sausages. Loud when used in musical instruments, or as a whip. You can make them into doughnut-shapes for easy storage, either by coiling it on itself or see "paracord doughnut" images on google

Comment: Not a bad answer but not what I'm looking for.  Some good fits though.  +1

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> A mirror?

I can walk and jump and make things me.

> Well, the mirror per se can't, but the mirrored image can.

I can bring happiness, play sports, and cut

> People can feel happy when they see themselves in the mirror if they have a positive self-image. Mirror (glass) can cut. As playing sports you may be talking about the [*Mirror* newspaper](http://www.mirror.co.uk/).

I can possess great poise and beauty

> A mirror is a beauty accessory

I can be baked, loud and doughnut.

> A common process to make a mirror is by silvering glass which requires a heating step. As for a doughnut, you might be referring to dough mirror work.

Comment: It's not what I'm looking for.  Some nice explanations though.  +1

Comment: @BrentHackers Those were the only two I had in mind :p. Hope someone else find it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> A yo-yo?

I can walk and jump and make things me,

> Yo-yo tricks can make them walk and jump

I can bring happiness, play sports and cut,

> People have hours of fun with yo-yos, and there are competitions

I can possess great poise and beauty,

> Yo-yos are pretty, and in order to do tricks they have to be well balanced

I can be baked, loud and doughnut.

> Yo-yos can be loud if you throw it on a hard floor. Also there is food named Yo-yo bisicuts, http://www.food.com/recipe/yo-yo-biscuits-437806, so that means it can be baked and the biscuit looks like a doughnut.

Comment: I'm not a yo-yo.  Some good explanations though.  +1

Answer (score -2):

I really want to say:

> a blade of grass or a maple tree/seed

(If I get it right, I'll say why.)

Comment: It's not a blade of grass.